# footnote resets on every section but i want it reset on every page

Tags: footnotes

I have this problem with footnotes on every section.

i have two sections in one page and each of them has a footnote in it and the footnotes reset after the first section ends

it somehow seems section dependent although i have used the package :

```
\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}
```

the problem is it is not working as it should be just resetting at every page.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I have tried that and the problem is it resets at every section not every page.

Comment: This should work. Please provide a MWE (minimal Working Example) which will demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution not knowing what caused it:

just used this package than the one mentioned in the question.

```
\usepackage{perpage} %the perpage package
\MakePerPage{footnote} %the perpage package command
```